# NGCC 1277-- a recoil ejection?

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, gravitational-waves

Recent calculations agree that a merging pair of supermassive black holes can emit enough gravitational waves to eject themselves from a galaxy.

Could NGCC 1277, a small galaxy with a 17 billion solar-mass black hole (see the [Nature article](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v491/n7426/full/nature11592.html)), be the result of such an ejection? The black hole would have had to drag along, or gather up, enough additional matter to form/constitute the small galaxy. Is this plausible, or at least possible?

Comment: I think the question would be somewhat improved by links pointing at papers, blog posts or other resources for the introductory context. Not that I doubt you, rather I'd like to read about it...

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is "No", since the galaxy NGC 1277 is much too large to possibly be bound to its SMBH.

Theoretical studies of recoiling SMBHs (e.g., [Merritt et al. (2009)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2009ApJ...699.1690M/abstract) suggest they could retain a small, compact cluster of stars from the parent galaxy: a "hypercompact stellar system" (HCSS).  The calculations in the Merritt et al. paper suggest that a SMBH with mass $\sim 10^{10}$ solar masses would take with it a collection of stars with a radius of $\sim 10$ pc and mass $\sim 10^{8}$ solar masses.

But NGC 1277 has a size of several *kiloparsecs* and a total stellar mass of $\sim 1-2 \times 10^{11}$ solar masses (about twice the stellar mass of the Milky Way), so it is orders of magnitude too large (in size and mass) to be an HCSS.

I'll also note that in the years since this question was asked, better data and more detailed measurements have significantly lowered the estimated mass of the SMBH in NGC 1277. The more recent measurements suggest a SMBH mass of only $\sim 5 \times 10^{9}$ solar masses, though [Graham et al. (2016)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2016ApJ...819...43G/abstract) suggest it might be as low as $\sim 1 \times 10^{9}$ solar masses.

Answer (score 1):

A scenario like how you describe is definitely consistent with results form numerical relativity.  The key point is that almost half of the total power radiated by the gravitational waves in a merger event is radiated during the last half-orbit of the inspiraling holes.  This makes the gravitational wave profile's power heavily asymmetric, which causes a net momentum to be imparted to the merged BH.  Interestingly, this 'kick velocity' is typically relativistically small, but astronomically large, and, like you said, can often be faster than the escape velocity from the galaxy (note that, in contrast to intuition with the solar system, the masses of the central SMBH are typically between 1/10 and 1/100 of the total mass of the galaxy, so the effect of the SMBH on things like escape velocity is smaller than you would think), while retaining any stars and gas bound to the central object with an escape velocity less than the kick velocity.

That said, I'm no observationalist, so I can't tell you much about the features of this particular system.  The details of this qualitative description are computationally beyond what is appropriate for stack exchange (unless someone cleverer than me can throw something quantitative together), so I have to leave the description qualitative.